# List all the queries made to BigQuery with their processed bytes

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know if there is a method in the BigQuery API or any other way where i can list all the queries made and their processed bytes. Something like what is listed in the Activity Page but with the processedBytes field:

https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?project=coherent-server-125913

We are having a problem with billing. Suddenly our BigQuery Analysis Costs have increased a lot and we think we are being charged like 20 times more than expected (we check all the responses from BigQuery API and save the processedBytes field, taking into account that the minimum charge is of 10MB).

The only way we can solve this difference is listing all the requests and comparing to our numbers to see if we aren´t measuring something or if we are doing something wrong. We have opened a billing support ticket and they have redirected me to Stackoverflow for asking the question as they think that is a technical issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking  totalBytesProcessed - you should try checking totalBytesBilled and billingTier (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#resource-representations))
You might jumped to high billing tiers - just guess

Comment: Thanks Mihaill, sometimes we only have the totalBytesProcessed in the response object. Finally we found that the problem was that Bigquery bills 10MB as a minimum per table per query. We thought it was 10MB per query.

Comment: @Mikhail -Just curious, let's say I have a query which consumes 2.3 MB of data (As I can see on the BQ Console) and I am querying 1 BQ table of around 2 GB of data. Then will my billing be 10MB(considering min) + 2.3 = 12.3 MB?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to check would be the BigQuery logs.

This is going to tell you what queries were run, who ran them, what date/time they were run, the total bytes billed etc.

Logs can be a bit tedious to look through but BigQuery allows you to stream BigQuery logs into a BigQuery table and you can then query said table to identify expensive queries.

I've done this and it works really well to give you visibility on your BQ charges. The process of how to do this is outlined in more detail here: https://www.reportsimple.com.au/post/google-bigquery